# Geometric explanation of the structure of a local Artinian ring.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be an affine commutative algebra over the complex numbers with unit.  Suppose that $m\leq A$ is a maximal ideal and $k$ a counting number so that $m^k=m^{k+1}$.
The algebra  $A/m^k$ is a local Artinian ring.   We can form the graded object
$$A/m\oplus m/m^2 \oplus \ldots m^{k-1}/m^k $$
The $0$th term $A/m=k$ is the residue field at the point. The next term $m/m^2$ is
The dual to the Zariski tangent space.  What about the rest? Is there some geometric explanation of the other quotients?  How about a homological explanation? Where can I learn about this object?  Thanks for anything you are willing to share.

Comment: This is the normal cone.